# for loop to display the array in the correct format using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching  the records from the database using the following code snippet:

```
if($pdo)
{
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT ID,Province,City,Position,Locale FROM jobs');
$result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print("<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>");
}
```

I am getting the array :

I would like to retrieve the values using for each loop and display on the website:

```
Province name
     city name:
     position name1:
     position name 2:
province name
      city name:
      Position  name 3:
      Position  name 4:
```

I Have written the code :

```
<?foreach($result as $key=>$val):?> 
    <div class='r-wr'>
        <h2 class="region-heading"><?=$key?></h2>
            <?foreach($val as $city=>$result):?>
            <div class='c-wr'>
                <h3 class="city-heading"><?=$city?></h3>
                        <?foreach($result as $pos_key=>$position):?>
                    <div class="pstn-btn" position-id="<?=$pos_key;?>"><?=$position;?></div><br>
                    <?endforeach;?>
                    </div>
            <?endforeach;?>
            </div>
    <?endforeach;?>
```

can anyone please  help me how to write the for each loop to get the record values.

Thanks

Comment: Post your implementation

Comment: `foreach ($result as $row) { echo $row['City']; ... }`

Comment: please see the code added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $key=>$val){
    $res[$val['Province']][$val['City']][$val['ID']] = $val['Position'];
}
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [BC] => Array
        (
            [Winnipeg] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Licensed Technician - Body Technician
                )

        )

    [Prairies] => Array
        (
            [Winnipeg] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Licensed Technician - Body Technician
                )

            [Edmonton] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Tire Technician
                )

        )

    [Ontario] => Array
        (
            [Regional Support Centre (Mississauga)] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Customer Service Representative
                    [5] => Payroll and Benefits Administrator
                )

            [Mississauga] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Shunt-Delivery Driver
                    [7] => Technician
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($result as $row) { 
   echo "Province Name ".$row['Province']."
;
   echo "City Name ".$row['City']."
;
   echo "Position Name ".$row['Position']."
;
}

Answer (score 0):

i run demo it

```
<?php

$result = array(
  array(
    'ID' => 1,
    'Province' => 'BC',
    'City' => 'Winnipeg',
    'Position' => 'Licensed Technician - Body Technician',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 2,
    'Province' => 'Prairies',
    'City' => 'Winnipeg',
    'Position' => 'Licensed Technician - Body Technician',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 3,
    'Province' => 'Prairies',
    'City' => 'Edmonton',
    'Position' => 'Tire Technician',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 4,
    'Province' => 'Ontario',
    'City' => 'Regional Support Centre (Mississauga)',
    'Position' => 'Payroll and Benefits Representative',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 5,
    'Province' => 'Ontario',
    'City' => 'Regional Support Centre (Mississauga)',
    'Position' => 'Payroll and Benefits Administrator',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 6,
    'Province' => 'Ontario',
    'City' => 'Mississauga',
    'Position' => 'Shunt-Delivery Driver',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  ),
  array(
    'ID' => 7,
    'Province' => 'Ontario',
    'City' => 'Mississauga',
    'Position' => 'Technician',
    'Locale' => 'en'
  )
);

$temp = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$value['Province']][$value['City']][] = $value['Position'];
}
print_r($temp);
```

And result:

```
Array
(
    [BC] => Array
        (
            [Winnipeg] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Licensed Technician - Body Technician
                )

        )

    [Prairies] => Array
        (
            [Winnipeg] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Licensed Technician - Body Technician
                )

            [Edmonton] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Tire Technician
                )

        )

    [Ontario] => Array
        (
            [Regional Support Centre (Mississauga)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Payroll and Benefits Representative
                    [1] => Payroll and Benefits Administrator
                )

            [Mississauga] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Shunt-Delivery Driver
                    [1] => Technician
                )

        )

)
```

I hope it work for you

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've messed with PHP, but you could use `array_reduce` to build a new hash based on Province and nest matching records under that key, that will make it much easier to iterate over:

```
<?php
$data = [array(
'id' => 1,
'Province' => 'Ontario',
'Position' => 'Customer Service',
), array(
'id' => 2,
'Province' => 'Ontario',
'Position' => 'Customer Service II',
), array(
'id' => 3,
'Province' => 'Edmunton',
'Position' => 'Janitor',
), array(
'id' => 4,
'Province' => 'Edmunton',
'Position' => 'Tire Technician',
)];

$provincePositions = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['Province'], $carry)) {
        array_push($carry[$item['Province']], $item);
    } else {
        $carry[$item['Province']] = [$item];
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

foreach($provincePositions as $province => $positions) {
    echo $province . "\n";
    foreach ($positions as $position) {
        echo "\t" . $position['Position'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Ontario
        Customer Service
        Customer Service II
Edmunton
        Janitor
        Tire Technician
```